# Replace GET variable value in PHP

Tags: php

everyone.

Is it possible to replace a specific GET variable value by using RegEx?

Here is what I have in mind.

I have a URL: https://example.com/category/?var1=value1&page=2&var2=value2

It can have different GET variables, but the one that it always has is "page".

What I want to do is this:

1. Set the URL value to a string variable in PHP code - Done.
   `$current_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`
2. In that string replace the value of the "page" variable with another value but keep the rest of the URL the same so that I could use them for paging buttons - Struggling
3. Take the string variable and echo it in a href tag - Done.
   `<a href="<?php echo $current_link_next; ?>">Next</a>`

The "page" value, of course, is not always 2 - it represents the page number where the user currently is so can be anything from 1 to any other integer.

I'm trying to do it with explodes and joins, but haven't succeeded yet. Maybe there is an easier way to replace values using RegEx?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Do you want to do it as a rewrite/redirect, before page loads, or during page load?

Comment: Why not use `$_GET`  for this?

Comment: I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to replace a parameter. Note, however, that this solution doesn't necessarily work out of the box for all URLs as some may not have a `query`.

```php
# Your URL.
$url = "https://example.com/category/?var1=value1&page=2&var2=value2";

# Parse your URL to get its composing parts.
$parts = parse_url($url);

# Save the query of the URL.
$query = $parts["query"];

# Parse the query to get an array of the individual parameters.
parse_str($query, $params);

# Replace the value of the parametre you want.
$params["page"] = "your-value";

# Build the query.
$newQuery = http_build_query($params);

# Replace the old query with the new one.
$newUrl = str_replace($query, $newQuery, $url);
```

[Snippet](https://onlinephp.io/c/46c14)